# Python request to get JSON

Tags: python, dictionary, iteration

This is my request.

```
h="API-AUTHENTICATION:key:secret"
r=requests.get("https://URL", h)
```

This is the response:
`<Response [200]>`

If I print the plain text of the request `(print(r.text))` I get this:

```
{
    "status": "OK",
    "data": [
        {
            "sort": 1,
            "parent_name": "Stocktake Demo",
            "timetables": [
                {
                    "active": 1,
                    "from_date": "Nov 01, 2019",
                    "timetable_data": {
                        "monday": [
                            {
                                "to": "23:59",
                                "from": "00:00"
                            }
                        ],
                        "tuesday": [
                            {
                                "to": "23:59",
                                "from": "00:00"
                            }
                        ],
                        "friday": [
                            {
                                "to": "23:59",
                                "from": "00:00"
                            }
                        ],
                        "wednesday": [
                            {
                                "to": "23:59",
                                "from": "00:00"
                            }
                        ],
                        "thursday": [
                            {
                                "to": "23:59",
                                "from": "00:00"
                            }
                        ],
                        "sunday": [
                            {
                                "to": "23:59",
                                "from": "00:00"
                            }
                        ],
                        "saturday": [
                            {
                                "to": "23:59",
                                "from": "00:00"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "type": 1,
                    "to_date": ""
                }
            ],
            "name": "Stocktake Food",
            "parent_id": 137585,
            "parent_sort": 73,
            "image": null,
            "id": 137586,
            "description": null
        },
        {
            "sort": 1,
            "parent_name": "Main Category",
            "timetables": [
                {
                    "active": 1,
                    "from_date": "Nov 01, 2019",
                    "timetable_data": {
                        "monday": [
                            {
                                "to": "23:59",
                                "from": "00:00"
                            }
                        ],
                        "tuesday": [
                            {
                                "to": "23:59",
                                "from": "00:00"
                            }
                        ],
                        "friday": [
                            {
                                "to": "23:59",
                                "from": "00:00"
                            }
                        ],
                        "wednesday": [
                            {
                                "to": "23:59",
                                "from": "00:00"
                            }
                        ],
                        "thursday": [
                            {
                                "to": "23:59",
                                "from": "00:00"
                            }
                        ],
                        "sunday": [
                            {
                                "to": "23:59",
                                "from": "00:00"
                            }
                        ],
                        "saturday": [
                            {
                                "to": "23:59",
                                "from": "00:00"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "type": 1,
                    "to_date": ""
                }
            ],
            "name": "Main Subcategory",
            "parent_id": 117042,
            "parent_sort": 2,
            "image": null,
            "id": 117043,
            "description": null
        }
    ]
}
```

If I do this:

```
a=json.loads(r.text)
print(a.keys())
print(a)
```

I get this:

```
dict_keys(['status', 'data'])
```

How to parse this into a dictionary and iterate it. Now when I iterate it I only reach status and data fields. I try to iterate it like this:

```
def print_depth(a, start=0):
    for key, value in a.items():
        print(key, start + 1)
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            print_depth(value, start=start + 1)
print_depth(a)
```

Comment: u can use `r.json()` to get the return value as json

Comment: print(r.json()) => <Response [200]>

Comment: Should I add r.json() into the request? If yes, maybe you could give me an example? that would extremely useful.

Comment: What is your desired output

Comment: My ultimate goal is to sort an item that has id: 137586. So I am trying to iterate the json to print out the whole item.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`response.json()`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content) will give you json, if response contains a **valid** JSON.
You can check the 'content type' in the header of the response payload to verify whether response is a json or not using `response.headers.get('Content-Type')`

```
import requests
response = requests.get('https://api.github.com')
if response.status_code == 200 and 'application/json' in response.headers.get('Content-Type',''):
    print(response.json())
```

your response is a json with 2 keys `status` and `data`, you can access them directly from the json and iterate on `data` value which is a list

```
h="API-AUTHENTICATION:key:secret"
r=requests.get("https://URL", h)
if r.json().get('status') == 'OK':
    for item in r.json().get('data'):
        print(item.items())
```

Comment: Maybe you know why this did not work? if item.get('id') == 117042:

Comment: I put it between the for and the last line.

Comment: may be there is no `id`==117042, just print all the `id`'s in the dicionary and verify. `print(item.get('id'))`

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
import json
import requests
url = 'https://..........'
response = requests.get(url)
if response.status_code == 200:
    my_dict = json.loads(response.content.decode('utf-8'))
```